# Get JS to recognize white spaces .split()

Tags: javascript, split

I wrote this function to log a new string from the given string where the letters should be the following one in the alphabet and all of the vowels would be uppercase.

Now I have the issue of not being able to split the string the way I want it. Right now the words are being split into separate characters in an array when I'd really like the string to be split on the white spaces. Could anybody explain why this is happening?

And when I put a space between the "" in the split method I just get all the characters and "undefined" where the white spaces should be. Thanks for your help!

```
function replace(str) {
  var newStr = [];
  var vowels = 'aeiou';
  var alpha = [  'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'
             ];
  str = str.split("");
  newStr.length = str.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
      if(alpha[i] === str[j]) {
         newStr[j] = (alpha[i + 1]);
      }
    }
  }
  for(var k = 0; k < vowels.length; k++) {
    for(var x =0; x < newStr.length; x++){
      if(vowels[k] === newStr[x]) {
        newStr[x] = vowels[k].toUpperCase("");
    }
  }
}
  return newStr;
}

console.log(replace("today is great"));
```

Comment: I get `[ 'today', 'is', 'great' ]`. What is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is definitely in the logic following the split, not the split itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = str.split(" ");
```

This splits your string up into ["today", "is", "great"].

When you get to

```
if(alpha[i] === str[j]) {
```

you never get inside the if block because you are comparing "a" to "today" or "a" to "is", etc. You'll need to break your string up even more to get this done I think.

I propose something like:

```
function replace(str) {
    var alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'],
        vowels = 'aeiou',
        newStr = [],
        i, j, k;

    // split everything into words
    str = str.split(' ');

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        // split everything into letters
        str[i] = str[i].split('');

        // make sure newStr has a similarly construction to str
        newStr[i] = [];

        for (j = 0; j < str[i].length; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < alpha.length; k++) {
                if (alpha[k] === str[i][j]) {

                    // subsitute each letter
                    newStr[i][j] = alpha[k + 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {

        // join newStr up to be an array of words instead of an array of an array of letters
        newStr[i] = newStr[i].join('');

        for (k = 0; k < vowels.length; k++) {

            // replace each vowel with the uppercase version
            newStr[i] = newStr[i].replace(vowels[k], vowels[k].toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    return newStr;
}
```

If you actually want to see "UpEbz jt hsfbU" instead of ["UpEbz", "jt", "hsfbU"], just change return newStr to return newStr.join(' ');

Comment: thanks greg. i'm new to js, so thanks for thoroughly explaining your function.

Answer (score 0):

To split string on whitespace try:

```
str = str.split(/\s+/);
```